# I am getting 'Application did not respond' without errors in console

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm getting 'Application did not respond' in Discord, but without any errors in console
This is all in a command handler.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('user')
        .setDescription('she shows you when user joined'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply(`user ${interaction.user.username} asked when he joined. he joined on ${interaction.member.joinedAt}.`);
    },
};
```

I have tried following the Discord.JS official documentation/guides to get this far.

Comment: You should also include that part where you call `execute`.

Answer (score 0):

**DiscordJS** requires an acknowledgement from your bot within three seconds that the interaction was received, either meaning you need to respond or defer the interaction.

##### Deferring the Command

In your command handler, you can immediately defer the command

```js
await interaction.deferReply();
```

[Docs: CommandInteraction # deferReply](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=deferReply)

**NOTE** after deferring the interaction, you CANNOT reply to it. You will then need to use `interaction # followUp` which takes the same parameter as `reply`.